# バッチ処理で指定文字列を含まないファイルを削除するには？

Tags: windows, batch-file

windows10 64bit環境です。
//forで.mp3ファイルを順に処理対象にする

```
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.mp3') do (
    echo.%%a
)
```

//hogeを含まない.mp3を削除
//仮にfuga.mp3が処理対象だったら

```
set str1=fuga.mp3
if x%str1:hoge=%==x%str1% (
    del %str1%
)
```

これらを組み合わせて

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.mp3') do (
    set str1=%%a
    if x!str1:hoge=!==x!str1! (
        echo.!str1!
    )
)
pause
```

このように処理したのですが
エラーなのかすぐにコマンド入力画面が消えます。
そしてファイルも削除できません。

解決方法をお教えいただけると大変助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コードだけ貼り付けて表題の意図を理解しろ…というのは少し乱暴すぎませんかね？、そもそもコードが間違っているから意図した動作でないわけですよね？なら、その意図した動作を教えていただかないと回答できないのでは？また、環境等も合わせて記載するとより良いです。

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました。
おっしゃる通りです。
補足しましたのでご覧いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cmd.exeを立ち上げておいてその中で提示されたbatを実行すると、pauseに至る前に下記のコードで`=!==x!str1! の使い方が誤っています。`というエラーを吐いて終了します。
`pause`に至る前に終了しているので、エラーを吐いてすぐにコマンド入力画面が消えます。

```
if x!str1:hoge=!==x!str1! (
```

単純にファイル名に特定の文字を含まないファイルを削除するだけなら、下記のコードで実現できそうですがいかがでしょうか。

```
rem ファイル名に"fuga"を含まないものをすべて削除する
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.mp3 ^| find /V "fuga"') do del %%a
```

ただしこのコードはフォルダを再帰的にたどってファイルを削除できません。
再帰的に削除したい場合は改修が必要なのでご留意願います。

※`dir`に`/s`スイッチを追加することで再帰的に削除すること自体は可能ですが、その場合フォルダ名まで削除判定文字列に含まれてしまうため。fugaフォルダ内のファイルは削除されません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
問題なく実現できました。
findはファイル対象かと思いこんでいましたが
このように指定すれば文字列でも使えるのですね。
まさかIFなしで実現できるとは思いませんでした。
今回はありがとうございました。